# Is the bifunctor of a monoidal category faithful?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\otimes: C\times C\to C$ be the bifunctor of a monoidal functor $C$ with left unitor $\rho$ and right unitor $\lambda$, and identity object $e$.

By using the naturality of $\rho$ I can show that if $f_1\neq f_2$, then $1_{e}\otimes f_1\neq 1_e \otimes f_2$, hence $g\otimes f_1\neq g\otimes f_2$ for any morphism $g$. Similarly if $f_1\neq f_2$, then $f_1\otimes g\neq f_2\otimes g$.

However is it true if $f_1\neq f_2$ and $g_1\neq g_2$, then $f_1\otimes g_1\neq f_2\otimes g_2$?

Comment: "hence $g\otimes f_1\neq g\otimes f_2$ for any morphism $g$" does not follow.

Comment: I see, it would only be true if $g$ has the form $g:e\to w$.

Comment: No, not even then.  For instance in abelian groups with the tensor product, $g$ could be $0$.

Comment: I guess it'd only be true if $f_1$, $f_2$ and $g$ are all isomorphisms, since $(f_1\otimes g)^{-1} = f_1^{-1}\otimes g^{-1} \neq (f_2\otimes g)^{-1}$.

Comment: No, not even then.  Like in the example in my answer with abelian groups, you can take $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be different automorphisms of an abelian group and then tensor with an automorphism of a different abelian group such that the tensor product is trivial.

Comment: But I don’t understand the flaw of my reasoning. Surely if they have different inverses then they are different?

Comment: Why are the inverses different, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101418/discussion-between-sid-caroline-and-eric-wofsey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are counterexamples even to the cases you claim to have solved.  For instance, if $C=\mathtt{Set}$ and $\otimes$ is the categorical product then all functions become the same when you take the product with a function whose domain is the empty set.

Or, for a counterexample where both pairs of maps are distinct, if $C=\mathtt{Ab}$ and $\otimes$ is the tensor product, you could take $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{Z}/(2)\to \mathbb{Z}/(2)$ to be the two different maps and $g_1,g_2:\mathbb{Z}/(3)\to\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ to be the two different maps and then $f_1\otimes g_1=f_2\otimes g_2$ since $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\otimes\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ is trivial.